# What's good memory usage for a basic code igniter script with no queries?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a simple page, nothing excessive, and no queries.  The memory usage is `1,924,560 bytes`.  I'm not sure how that compares.  I'm running code igniter

Comment: The total memory usage or that specific process memory usage ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Profiling: Memory Usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562547/application-profiling-memory-usage)

Comment: To start with you should create a empty PHP file and see what the memory usage is. The memory usage will include the entire PHP process and any extensions you're running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's nearly exactly what my project started out at. I'd say that's probably just the overhead of PHP and CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty fair. My script is not so basic yet my memory usage is 2.7MB

However I'd be glad to know mor about it or at least more results to compare with.

Answer (score 0):

I just started a project with almost not logic added and I am at 2.43mb.